# jQuery addition and subtraction won't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0br4crLe/2/

The goal here is to make each item for the + and - work independently.

Right now when you click on the + or - button on 1 item, it will affect all of the items from top to bottom. See screenshot below:

[image]

It must work independently. Let's say I click on  the + button on 1 item, it must only work on that particular item w/o affecting the other items.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('input[name="plus1"]').click(function(){
debugger;
var number_text = $('input[name="fname1"]').val();
if(number_text>=0){
number_text = Number(number_text);
number_text=number_text+1;
$('input[name="fname1"]').val(number_text);
}

});
$('input[name="minus1"]').click(function(){
debugger;
var number_text = $('input[name="fname1"]').val();
if(number_text>=1){
number_text = Number(number_text);
number_text=number_text-1;
$('input[name="fname1"]').val(number_text);
}

});
```

tried to work things, but doesnt work, any idea? can you show me the fiddle option to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I tried it in JSFIDDLE, it works.

Comment: @Dere0405: It works dependently. It must work independently. When you click on the + button it will affect all item from top to bottom. It must only affect the item you click on not all of it. Do you know the idea to make it like on JSFIDDLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so clean but you can give each button a class (`minus` or `plus`), then call those using `jQuery`.

HTML:

```
      <input type="button" name="minus1" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus">
      <input type="text" name="fname1" value="2" class="value">
      <input type="button" name="plus1" value="+" id="plus1" class="plus">
```

Then use `.prev()` or `.next()` to get to the input textbox element and then its value.

JS:

```
$('.plus').click(function() {
  var number_text = $(this).prev(); // gets the input textbox element next to the plus button
  var number_value = number_text.val(); // gets the input textbox element's current value
  if (number_value >= 0) {
    number_value = Number(number_value);
    number_value = number_value + 1;
    number_text.val(number_value);
  }

});
$('.minus').click(function() {
  var number_text = $(this).next(); // gets the input textbox element next to the minus button
  var number_value = number_text.val(); // gets the input textbox element next to the minus button
  if (number_value >= 1) {
    number_value = Number(number_value);
    number_value = number_value - 1;
    number_text.val(number_value);
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0br4crLe/3/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are effecting every element in the collection, based on you're jQuery selector. Without using `.each()` I think this should work:

```
$('input[name="plus1"]').click(function(){
  var out = $(this).prev();
  out.val(+out.val()+1);
});
$('input[name="minus1"]').click(function(){
   var out = $(this).next();
   if(+out.val()){
     out.val(+out.val()-1);
   }
});
```

Your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0br4crLe/4/) has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give every button a different name in the HTML. For example, "minus2" for the second button, "minus3" for the third, etcetera.

Comment: Can you show me the option idea codes on JSFIDDLE please? I want to see it real action.

Comment: Beyond someone just fixing it for you, I hope you understand why.